# Troubleshooting "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when traversing Wordpress JSON feed

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I need to retrieve tags for WordPress posts in a JSON feed script. The code below was in the original script, but it breaks if posts don't have more than two tags and throws the warning `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

```
$tags = array();
foreach((get_the_tags()) as $tag) {
    $tags[] = $tag->name; 
}
$single["tags"] = $tags;
```

Here's some code that I updated to get it to work if there are less than two tags, but this will cause all tags to be appended to the next post in the each. So if the first post has "tag1" and "tag2" and the second has "tag3" and "tag4", the third post in the JSON feed will have tags such as "tag1", "tag2", "tag3", tag4", and "tag5" (even if it should just have "tag5".

```
$my_tags = get_the_tags();
if ($my_tags){
    foreach($my_tags as $tag) {
        $tags[] = $tag->name; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply reset your `$tags` array with a `$tags = array()` before starting each new post.

Comment: Is your code snippet may be place inside another loop that lopps over all your singles. Do you empty the tags array before you start reading the tags for the next single?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a function to check if it is an array, it's named `is_array()`, read more -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

```
if (is_array($my_tags)){
```

also empty that array each time you loop through a post, just by adding the code from your first example:

```
$my_tags = array();
$my_tags = get_the_tags();
if (is_array($my_tags)){
```